# Return multiple variables to JavaScript from COM

Tags: javascript, c++, com

I have COM function in a `disp` interface as shown below,

```
[id(1)] HRESULT MultipleReturn([out]BSTR* arg1, [out, retval] BSTR* arg2);
```

implemented as

```
STDMETHODIMP SomeCoolObject::MultipleReturn(BSTR* arg1, BSTR* arg2)
{
    *arg1 = SysAllocString(L"test1");
    *arg2 = SysAllocString(L"test2");
    return S_OK;
}
```

In Python I can call it as

```
import comtypes.client as cc

obj = cc.CreateObject('SomeCoolObject')
a = obj.MultipleReturn()
print(a) # gives (u'test1', u'test2'), Python, I see you don't bite :)
```

same in JavaScript

```
var obj = new ActiveXObject("SomeCoolObject")

// this gives error, kind of obvious
// 'Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment'
// var val = obj.MultipleReturn();

var a = "holaaa!";
var val = obj.MultipleReturn(a);
alert(val); // gives "test2"
alert(a);   // gives "holaaa!", may be could have given "test1"
```

this proves, JavaScript won't play this ball. Why? If not, then how do you return multiple values from COM to JavaScript.
For this particular job, I returned a JSON though.

Comment: I'd think about a SafeArray or in that direction.

Comment: Yes. I thought about using `SAFEARRAY` but question is about collecting two `[out]` variables in JavaScript. Not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript/COM binding doesn't support `[out]` parameters - only `[out, retval]` (of which, of course, there can only be one). JavaScript generally doesn't have a notion of pass-by-reference.

There are several ways you can get closer to your goal.

1. Return a `SAFEARRAY` of two strings. In JavaScript, consume it via [`VBArray` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y39d47w8.aspx).
2. Implement a simple COM object with two `BSTR` properties, create and return an instance of that object via `[out, retval] IDispatch**`.
3. Take `IDispatch*` as an `[in]` parameter, set a new property on it via `IDispatchEx::GetDispID(fdexNameEnsure)`. JavaScript would consume it like this:

.

```
var outParam = {};
var result = obj.MultipleReturn(outParam);
var secondResult = outParam.value;
```

(where `value` is the name of the property your method creates on the object).

Comment: It's not JavaScript per se, it's COM automation (late-binding, dispatching, whatever it's called these days) that only supports `[out, retval]`.

Comment: @PauloMadeira Nothing in Automation spec precludes `[out]` parameters. They work fine with VB, VBA and VBScript. So no, it's specifically JavaScript, and its COM binding, that have this limitation.

Comment: You're right.  But with late binding, you have to inform the language of such arguments (e.g. `ByRef`).  I'm almost sure the op's Python code, as-is, could only return those values with early binding.  So, it's not even a fair comparison with the VB* languages.

Comment: @PauloMadeira I'm not familiar with Python/COM binding. My guess would be, it's reading the type library, via `IDispatch::GetTypeInfo`. The information about parameter types and direction of data flow is available there. I don't see any evidence of early binding in the sample shown.

Comment: You're right again.  I can't bother to check comtypes' code right now, but that's plausible.